# How to add a view to content build with bricks module

Tags: 8

I have installed the modules bricks and eck (entity construction kit). Then I tried to add a VIEW to content build with the bricks and eck modules, but without success. Can anybody help what's wrong or does anybody know wether it is in general possible to add a view or not?

This is my view:
[image]

The following images show what I have done.

Step 1: 
[image: add component bundle]

Step 2:

I also tried to use a CONTENT-FIELD
[image: add a new field to component bundle]

Step 3:
[image: reference to a view]

Step 4:
[image]

Step 5: [image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with those Views? Use them on node form with Bricks to choose some other articles as references?

Comment: yes, that's what I want to do